# Is the most basic First Law equation of Thermodynamics valid only in ideal cases?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, work, physical-chemistry

Consider the First Law in Physics:
$$ dq = du + dw $$
Here dw refers to work done by System.

In Chemistry the First becomes:
$$ dq = du - dw$$
Here the work is the work done by surroundings .

In ideal cases - massless piston , work done by System is equal to the work done by surroundings.

Now I am aware that above laws may need modifications for real cases.

---

My question is till when can I use the law in the the form above without any modifications? Can this be done only for ideal and frictionless piston?

Comment: Note that if the piston is not frictionless, some of the energy you're trying to put into the system by compressing it ($\text dw$) will not end up entering the system.

Comment: @Charlie Sir I suppose that means that the equation is only in ideal case.

Comment: No.  These equations in terms of differentials are only valid for reversible processes.